# ImageMagick complains when image is missing while stitching together tiles of an image

Tags: mac, command-line, bash

I have to stitch together pictures (first vertically, then horizontally) with a varying amount of tiles via the command line on `macOS 10.14.5`. I usually use this command:

```
convert -append 0_0.jpeg 0_1.jpeg 0_2.jpeg 0_3.jpeg 0_4.jpeg 0_5.jpeg 0a.jpg &&
convert -append 1_0.jpeg 1_1.jpeg 1_2.jpeg 1_3.jpeg 1_4.jpeg 1_5.jpeg 1a.jpg &&
convert -append 2_0.jpeg 2_1.jpeg 2_2.jpeg 2_3.jpeg 2_4.jpeg 2_5.jpeg 2a.jpg &&
convert -append 3_0.jpeg 3_1.jpeg 3_2.jpeg 3_3.jpeg 3_4.jpeg 3_5.jpeg 3a.jpg &&
convert -append 4_0.jpeg 4_1.jpeg 4_2.jpeg 4_3.jpeg 4_4.jpeg 4_5.jpeg 4a.jpg &&
convert -append 5_0.jpeg 5_1.jpeg 5_2.jpeg 5_3.jpeg 5_4.jpeg 5_5.jpeg 5a.jpg &&
convert -append 6_0.jpeg 6_1.jpeg 6_2.jpeg 6_3.jpeg 6_4.jpeg 6_5.jpeg 6a.jpg &&
convert +append 0a.jpg 1a.jpg 2a.jpg 3a.jpg 4a.jpg 5a.jpg 6a.jpg 0_final.jpg
```

where I first add all corresponding tiles vertically (here 6 tiles) and then add all columns (here 7) horizontally to the final picture.

The issue is that sometimes, I have less pictures in a column (0 to 4 instead of 0 to 5 as given here) or more columns (0 to 10 instead of 0 to 6 as shown here).

Is it possible to adjust the above command so that `imagemagick` does not complain that, for example, picture `0_5.jpg` or `7_0.jpg` does not exist? Currently `imagemagick` complains and stops the process of stitching together the existing tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with wildcards. The shell will expand to existing files:

```
convert -append 0_*jpeg 0a.jpg &&
convert -append 1_*jpeg 1a.jpg &&
convert -append 2_*jpeg 2a.jpg &&
convert -append 3_*jpeg 3a.jpg &&
convert -append 4_*jpeg 4a.jpg &&
convert -append 5_*jpeg 5a.jpg &&
convert -append 6_*jpeg 6a.jpg &&
convert +append *a.jpg 0_final.jpg
```